# How to append the text to the url as parameter when the link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please help me with my situation. I had a website with many web pages with hundreds of pages and thousands of links. Leave it. Let me say about my problem.

Let take a list

1. Fruit - Click Here1
2. Apple - Click Here2

where Click Here contains the link. Let take the example Click Here1 contains (www.example1.com). Click Here2 contains (www.example2.com)

What I trying is,

when clicked on Click Here1, it should open (www.example1.com#Fruit)
when clicked on Click Here2, it should open (www.example2.com#Apple)

So how to do that? I want the list text also to add with the link. Please help me

Comment: Add Id to your list container. ie. <div id="Fruit"><p>This is Fruit list...</p></div>

Comment: Maybe it could help, if you show some code that you already have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```js
let list = document.querySelector("ul");
list.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  if (e.target.nodeName !== "A") return;
  e.preventDefault();
  let hash = e.target.previousSibling.textContent.split(" ")[0];
  console.log(`${e.target.href.slice(0, -1)}#${hash}`);
  document.location.href = `${e.target.href.slice(0, -1)}#${hash}`;
});
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Fruit - <a href="http://www.example1.com">Click Here1</a></li>
  <li>Apple - <a href="http://www.example2.com">Click Here2</a></li>
</ul>
```

You listen for clicks on your list, then if a click happens in an anchor element, then you grab the previous sibling's text content (the fruit/apple) and append it to the new url with a prefixed hashtag.

Answer (score 0):

```js
if ('URLSearchParams' in window) {
    var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    searchParams.set("foo", "bar");
    window.location.search = searchParams.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am working for websites with Node.js Express and EJS templatings.
In my `app.js` I use this code:

(The page is named `post.ejs` in URL its "posts")

```
app.get("/posts/:postId", function(req, res) {
  const requestedPostId = req.params.postId;
  Post.findOne({
    _id: requestedPostId
  }, 

function(err, post) {
    res.render("post", {
    });
  });
});
```

Tell me If that helped.